# I am trying to create an iframe that changes when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am setting up a website and what I need is for when a button is clicked it changes the link in the iframe so it goes to another website. Here is what I got so far:

```
<script> 
var id = 'http://www.aWebsite.com';

    function link(){

    id = 'http://www.aSecondWebsite.com'

    }
    </script>
    <script>
       document.writeln('<iframe name="heel"src="' + id + '" height="300" width="700"> </iframe>');

    </script>

    <button onclick="link()">Click Me</button>
```

I am not sure why when the button is clicked the id variable isn't changed?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the value of `id` is changed, but `document.writeln()` is not in the `link` function, hence it's not executed.

A quick-fix would be to move the `document.writeln()` into `link()`, but that would be a disastrous fix. [`document.write(ln)()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.write) wipes out everything in the document, and creates a new one, when used after the page has been parsed. You need to do something like this:

```
function link() {
    id = 'http://www.example.org';
    document.getElementById('heel').src = id;
}
```

Then add your iframe element to a HTML, and remove the whole script with `document.writeln()`.

```
<iframe id="heel" name="heel" src="http://www.example.com" height="300" width="700"></iframe>
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to create a new `iframe` element, you can do it like this:

```
function link() {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe'); // creates an iframe element
    id = 'http://www.example.org';
    frame.width = '700px'; // sets the width for the new iframe
    frame.height = '300px'; // sets the height for the new iframe
    frame.name = 'heel2'; // sets the name for the new iframe
    frame.src = id; // sets the src for the new iframe
    document.body.appendChild(frame); // appends the new iframe to body as a last element   
}
```